# "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I2)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am getting below error in production instance. There were no changes to the ETL and the job was running all OK everyday. Today suddenly it has started failing with error:

> Source: SQL Update Audit Table Processing Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "UPDATE AuditTableProcessing  SET   ExtractRowCnt = ?..." failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I2)"

When I run the job in development environment everything runs smoothly without an issue. Any hints on the issue will be much helpful!

Comment: What's being used to populate the variable, and does the datatype of this data in your production environment match that in development?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that there are a Variable Mapped in the ResultSet of the Execute SQL Task is of type `DBTYPE_I2` and the value does not fit theis type, try changing it to `DBTYPE_I4` or relevant data type.

More information about ResulSet:

- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)